# cmake: Copy files to dependent targets (specifically for use in OpenCL)

Tags: c++, cmake, opencl

I am fiddling around with OpenCL, where files are typically compiled at runtime. The typical structure of a project looks like this:

```
foo/
  cl/foo.cl
  inc/foo.hpp
  src/foo.cpp
  CMakeLists.txt
```

where `foo.cpp` will have a command to build the OpenCL kernel. Something like:

```
buildKernelFromFile('cl/foo.cl'); // Note the relative path
```

To facilitate this, I have been setting up the `CMakeLists.txt` file to copy the `.cl` files to a `cl/` folder in the binary directory:

```
set(kernels
        foo.cl)
foreach (kernel IN ITEMS ${kernels})
    configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cl/${kernel} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cl/${kernel} COPYONLY)
endforeach ()
```

The issue is that when the `foo` project is an executable, then this approach is fine since the `.cl` files will be copied to the same location as the executable. However, when the `foo` project is a library, this approach no longer works because the relative path is to the binary directory of the library, not the binary directory of the executable using the library.

So what I would like is a way to somehow tell CMake to copy the `.cl` files to the binary directory of any dependent targets. Specifically, if I build the OpenCL project like this

```
add_library(foo foo.cpp)
```

and then in a separate CMakeLists.txt file, link to that project:

```
add_executable(something main.cpp)
target_link_library(something PRIVATE foo)
```

I need to copy my `.cl` files to the build folder `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` of the `something` target.

One thing I would like to avoid is having to save the .cl files as string literals and then using them like an include. (Ignore this comment if it does not make sense to you).

EDIT:

In the meantime, in the OpenCL library's CMakeLists.txt file (`foo/CMakeLists.txt`), I simply declared a function

```
# Copy the OpenCL kernels to the build folder
set(KERNEL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cl PARENT_SCOPE)
function(copy_kernels)
    set(kernels
            foo.cl)
    foreach (kernel IN ITEMS ${kernels})
        configure_file(${KERNEL_DIR}/${kernel} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cl/${kernel} COPYONLY)
    endforeach ()
endfunction()
```

which should be called by dependent projects. Then in the dependent project, in addition to linking to the `foo` target, you need to call this function

```
copy_kernels()
target_link_library(something PRIVATE foo)
```

I would like to figure out how to get rid of that `copy_kernels()` call, but I don't know cmake well enough to do that.

Comment: My `cmake` is kinda rusty, but I'd approach it with creating custom target via `add_custom_target` which copies `.cl` files into generator-expession based path (i.e. `cmake -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cl/file.cl $<TARGET_PROPERTY:BINARY_DIR>/cl/file.cl`). This generator expression means that target which is actually built will feed it's binary path into command. Then you add this custom target as `INTERFACE` dependency of library target. `INTERFACE` mean that this command's dependency will be forwarded to executable if it links to library via `PRIVATE` or `PUBLIC`.

Comment: I may try to do some minimal example tomorrow evening.

Answer (score 0):

Frustratingly there isn't a neat way of doing this in CMake. As you say,  `configure_file` should be exactly what we need, but it's not tied to a target and runs at configuration time (so you'd have to re-run cmake every time a kernel changed). The best I've been able to manage is this:

```
file(GLOB KERNELS cl/*.cl)
foreach(CurrentKernel IN LISTS KERNELS)
    cmake_path(GET CurrentKernel FILENAME FileName)
    add_custom_command(
                TARGET foo PRE_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${CurrentKernel} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cl/${FileName}
                COMMENT "Copying kernel: ${CurrenKernel}")
endforeach()
```